# Сравнение двух таблиц, вывод уникальных значений по одному столбцу

Tags: sql

Имеется 2 одинаковых таблицы. Допустим Лист1 и Лист2, в каждой таблице имеется один столбец Поле1.

Мне нужно сверить значения Лист2 с Лист1 и вывести только уникальные. (Хочу убрать дубли, которые имеются в Лист1). Другими словами. Мне нужно вывести только те значения Лист2, которых нет в Лист1.

Comment: не ясно что скрывается под словом "сверить", видимо вам нужен join. А уникальные дает ключевое слово distinct

Comment: Мне нужно вывести только те значения Лист2, которых нет в Лист1.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта.

Первый вам привёл @IgorSl:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT [Поле1]
FROM [Лист1]
WHERE 1 = 1
AND [Поле1] NOT IN (SELECT [Поле1] FROM [Лист2])
```

Второй через `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
      DISTINCT [Лист1].[Поле1]
FROM [Лист1]
LEFT JOIN [Лист2] ON [Лист1].[Поле1] = [Лист2].[Поле1] 
WHERE 1 = 1
AND [Лист2].[Поле1] IS NULL
```

В принципе, они эквиваленты. В разовом запросе на небольших данных да при отсутствии индекса по полю разницы особо не будет (и там и там в плане выполнения запроса будет table scan).

Answer (score 2):

В ANSI SQL Standard существует оператор `EXCEPT` предназначенный для получения разности множеств:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Поле1] FROM [Лист1]
EXCEPT
SELECT [Поле1] FROM [Лист2]
```

Насколько мне известно оператор `EXCEPT` реализован в `SQL Server`, `PostgreSQL`, `SQLite`, `IBM DB2`, `Oracle` (как `MINUS`), `H2`, `HSQLDB`, `Derby`:

В `Oracle` он называется `MINUS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Поле1] FROM [Лист1]
MINUS
SELECT [Поле1] FROM [Лист2]
```

[Таблица поддержки SQL функций/методов/операторов для различных реляционных СУБД (RDBMS)](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/dbms_comparison.html)

PS в `MySQL`, `MariaDB`, `Firebird` - оператор `EXCEPT/MINUS` не реализован.

Comment: Почему то пологал, что minus в стандарте, оказалось нет.  Взял на заметку.

Comment: Кстати, да: тоже вариант. Я про него вечно забываю, т.к. он не поддерживается в mysql - предпочитаю конструкции, которые с минимальными усилиями переносимы. Но это апвоут, однозначно.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct [Поле1] from [Лист1]
where [Поле1] not in (select [Поле1] from [Лист2])
```